# Excel (or Python/R/SQL): Putting all Matches in Separate Rows

Tags: python, sql, r, excel, match

I have two columns of data:

```
A    B
Dog  Cat
Cat  Car
Car  Pie
Car  Cat
Cat  Pie
```

What I would like is to create a third column, which matches the second column value to all occurrences of that value in the first column, and grabs the subsequent second column value to put into the third column of the original row we are looking at. Sorry for the confusing paragraph there, what it should look like is this:

```
A    B    C
Dog  Cat  Car
Dog  Cat  Pie
Cat  Car  Pie
Cat  Car  Cat
Car  Pie
Car  Cat  Car
Car  Cat  Pie
Cat  Pie
```

This is because it goes through, and for the first row it will see 'Cat' is the second column value, look for all matches in the first column (of which there are two) and their subsequent second column values (Car and Pie). It then creates a row where each of these subsequent values are displayed in the third column. There are no third column values for 'Car  Pie' or 'Cat  Pie' because no rows start with 'Pie' so there is nothing to match.

Hopefully this makes sense! If Excel isn't the right tool for this I'd be interested in other suggestions too, I know a bit of Python, R and SQL.

Comment: These are one of those questions we wish the OP could actually provide a data sample closer to actual data as this is too abstracted. Might get better response.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this in R:

```
TwoSteps <- [import dataframe here]

#Create an empty dataframe to hold all three-step transitions
ThreeSteps <- data.frame(First = character(),
                 Second=character(), 
                 Third=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Loop through all rows in TwoSteps. For each row,
#check all values in column 1 for matches. When a match is found,
#Add first and second from the original row to ThreeSteps First and Second, then
#Add second from matched row to Third

N = nrow(TwoSteps)
row = 1

for (i in 1:N) {
 for (g in 1:N){
   if(TwoSteps[i,2]==TwoSteps[g, 1]){
     ThreeSteps[row, 1] = TwoSteps[i, 1]
     ThreeSteps[row, 2] = TwoSteps[i, 2]
     ThreeSteps[row, 3] = TwoSteps[g, 2]
     row = row + 1
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in SQL using a left join with the same table:

```
Create Table #Example (A varchar(3), B varchar(3));

INSERT INTO #Example (A, B)
  values ('Dog', 'Cat'),
   ('Cat', 'Car'),
   ('Car', 'Pie'),
   ('Car', 'Cat'),
   ('Cat', 'Pie');

Select t1.*, t2.B as C
  from #Example t1
  left JOIN #Example t2 on t1.B=t2.A
```

The results are:

```
A   B   B1
Dog Cat Car
Dog Cat Pie
Cat Car Pie
Cat Car Cat
Car Pie (null)
Car Cat Car
Car Cat Pie
Cat Pie (null)
```